# Flash - Sound within Movieclip plays at random occasions

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Alright so I'm going crazy.

My flash project has 4 different scenes. A homepage and 3 subpages. There's also a navigation bar to switch between pages.

I have a MovieClip on the main page (and only on the main page) which plays on MOUSE_OVER. The MovieClip also contains a sound. The thing works perfectly. Animation and sound are played whenever I rollover. Now the weird thing:

The sound from my MovieClip also plays when I switch between scenes using my navigation bar. But not on every switch, only e.g from Page 1 to Page 3 but not to Page 2. All buttons are using the same function which simply say "gotoAndStop(...)". How can this be??

Comment: Could you explain how you play the `MovieClip` sound?
The sound plays with the animation of the `MovieClip`?

Comment: You must write your code !

Comment: There should be a code explorer in your IDE, the first thing to verify is if there's some code executing somewhere else. The second is to verify if you have other similar movieclips you think you've deleted in your scenes.

Comment: The sound was on a seperate layer in the MovieClip and starts with the animation. I changed it now so the sounds start via code.